# Best method to analyze external (nexus) dependencies in a "lift and shift" migration move?

Tags: java, maven, microservices, nexus

I'm carrying out a "lift and shift" migration of some functionality from a monolithic java spring application towards a standalone deployable.

The first snag I've run into is the project pulling references (through maven/nexus) to external APIs and not truly highlighting what areas of the codebase are dependent on code that is external to the project. Being that this is a large lift and shift, I need to identify the areas that are external, so I figure out the best way to not need those dependencies.

I've tried playing with the IntelliJ dependency tool, but it seems like it only analyzes dependencies within classes in the project itself. Is there a better tool to identify all the external classes / api's / services my app depends on?

Comment: What do you define as external dependencies? and what exactly do you mean by `lift and shift` migration?

Comment: Lift and shift meaning I'm copying all of the code from the monolith and dropping it into a new project, and then fixing the issues that come from that. There's more code that will remain functional with a dramatic move like that than code that will be broken. By external dependencies, I mean services that our application is interacting with by direct method calls, rather than through an API or endpoint. There's some instances where the "Person" repository is interacting with the "Car" repository (different domain in the real application) when the "Person" workflow shouldn't have access to it

Comment: If it's the dependency through direct methods calls, wouldn't the application classpath contain a list of the dependent jar files ?